# How to compare 2 rows of same table and return the difference between them using AWS Athena (SQL/presto)?

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, presto

I need to compare the two rows based on data1 and data2 columns only. So, if the data1 and data2 is same for both the rows, query should return nothing otherwise query should return the difference in data1 and data2.

in the below example in the row 1 adminaccess = false and row 2 adminacess =true how do i see the difference in the result ?(what will be the query to see the difference )

| data1 | data2 | createddate | modifiedon |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| { adminaccess=false, somedata=[], names=[{value=1.0, key=version}, {value=12, key=high}]} | {groups=['updated'], dataid=123, createdate={"2022-02-11T08:56:01Z"}} | "2022-07-22T07:25:19.501Z" | "2022-08-22T07:25:19.501Z" |
| {adminaccess=true, somedata=[], names=[{value=1.0, key=version}, {value=12, key=high}]} | {groups=[], dataid=123, createdate={"2022-02-11T08:56:01Z"}} | "2022-08-22T07:25:19.501Z" | "2022-07-22T07:25:19.501Z" |

required output

| data1 | data2 |
| --- | --- |
| {adminaccess=false} | {groups=['updated']} |

Comment: It's not obvious what you mean by "return the difference in data1 and data2". Can you provide a sample output you would like to see?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein required output is added in the question please refer above ,

The above output shows what has changed in row 1(latest data) compared to row 2(previous data) for the column data1 and data2. Also these two latest available rows should be sorted based on modifiedon column(Sorry for not clarifying this part earlier).


If there's no difference for we can return empty response.



Thanks.

Comment: you have to break/parse the JSON and compare each element and then return diff.